# Codeblocks: 'Class' was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, codeblocks, mingw32

So I am trying to compile a very simple project. For some reasons it doesn't find my class in the .cpp file.

Here is the code:
main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Dog.h"

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    Dog myDog;
    return 0;
}
```

Dog.h:

```
#ifndef DOG_H
#define DOG_H


class Dog
{
    public:
        Dog();
        virtual ~Dog();
        Dog(const Dog& other);
        Dog& operator=(const Dog& other);
    protected:
    private:
};

#endif // DOG_H
```

Dog.cpp:

```
#include "Dog.h"

Dog::Dog()
{
    //std::cout << "I'm alive!";
}

Dog::~Dog()
{
    //dtor
}

Dog::Dog(const Dog& other)
{
    //copy ctor
}

Dog& Dog::operator=(const Dog& rhs)
{
    if (this == &rhs) return *this; // handle self assignment
    //assignment operator
    return *this;
}
```

So that's pretty basic, still I get the error:  'Dog' was not declared in this scope.

I believe that i need to add this to the build, but I did that already by right clicking the dog.cpp in the projects window, and build settings.

[image: build settings of Dog.cpp]

Compiler log:

```
-------------- Build: Debug in MyProject (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

mingw32-g++.exe -Wall -fexceptions -g -Iinclude -c C:\Users\tamas\Documents\MyProject\include\Dog.cpp -o obj\Debug\include\Dog.o
mingw32-g++.exe -Wall -fexceptions -g -Iinclude -c C:\Users\tamas\Documents\MyProject\main.cpp -o obj\Debug\main.o
C:\Users\tamas\Documents\MyProject\main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
C:\Users\tamas\Documents\MyProject\main.cpp:9:5: error: 'Dog' was not declared in this scope
     Dog myDog;
     ^
C:\Users\tamas\Documents\MyProject\main.cpp:9:9: error: expected ';' before 'myDog'
     Dog myDog;
         ^
```

Comment: `include "Dog.h"` I assume this is a copy / paste error.

Comment: Yes, the # character is there actually!

Comment: In _what_ scope exactly Dog was not defined? (Compiler should've told you)

Comment: If Dog.cpp wasn't in the build, I suspect that you would be getting unresolved external symbol errors.

Comment: Readers are guessing in the dark till you post the compiler command and the compiler diagnostic. Get them from the **Build log** tab (not the **Build messages** tab). The code you have posted compiles and links in C::B.

Comment: I added the compiler log to this question.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code. This cannot be what you're _actually_ compiling (are you sure you don't have another `Dog.h` somewhere that's being used instead?), or something is very wrong with your toolchain. BTW why is there a .cpp file in a directory named "include"?

Comment: @JamesRoot I believe you were right about that Dog.cpp is not in the build? Check the compiler log

Comment: No, Dog.cpp is not the problem. Dog.h is the problem - however, again, its contents appear to be fine. So you're compiling some other Dog.h.

Comment: Ok, what `cpp main.cpp` shows? (remove `#include <iostream>` from main.cpp before executing command)

Comment: Yes, that was the  problem. I had another (old) Dog.h next to the main.cpp , while I intended to use include/Dog.h. Problem solved, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the correct Dog.h file was elsewhere where is should have been (in include/ directory).

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with the code you've posted in your question.

A few comments:

- Add `#include <iostream>` to Dog.cpp, so that you can uncomment the `cout` call in the `Dog()` constructor
- You could cause the error by commenting out `#include "Dog.h"` from main.cpp

  - This prevents the compiler from knowing what "Dog" is
- Another way to cause the error is if `DOG_H` is being defined, either:

  - manually as a compiler option.  (Ensure it's *not* being defined)
  - manually via an extra `#define`
  - automatically via some other header.  Ensure you haven't accidentally copied `DOG_H` into another header file.  (If your compiler supports using the nonstandard `#pragma once` you can use that instead of the include guards)

Comment: This isn't an answer, as far as I can tell.

Comment: #include is not commented out, also I removed the #IFNDEF and it's correspondent lines. But check the compiler log, perhaps that is where the error is?

Comment: @user2315991 `DOG_H` is not defined manually or before the `#include "Dog.h", correct?